# Hiding empty lines at the end of plain list items

Tags: org-mode

Can I prevent an empty line at the end of a plain list item from
showing when the item is folded?  For example, if I have

```
+ top

  wooden pole.  fireworks.

+ bottom
```

can I have it fold into

```
+ top...
+ botton
```

instead of

```
+ top...

+ bottom
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` excludes the trailing newlines from list items.

The replacement `my-org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` in the following code avoids that if there are subsequent list items in the same list.

Function `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` is used at quite a few places in orgmode. It seems better to me to keep the modification of `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` local to `org-cycle-internal-local` which controls the visibility of items.
Therefore the code below does not globally override `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` with `my-org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` via `advice-add` but overrides `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank` locally in an `:around`-advice for `org-cycle-internal-local`.

```el
(defun my-org-list-get-item-end-before-blank (item struct)
  "Override advice for `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank'.
Avoid skipping backwards empty lines if we are not at the end of the list."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (org-list-get-item-end item struct))
    (if (org-list-get-next-item item struct (org-list-prevs-alist struct))
        (forward-line -1)
      (skip-chars-backward " \r\t\n"))
    (point-at-eol)))

(defun ad-org-list-set-item-visibility (oldfun &rest args)
  "Hide empty lines at the end of plain list items.
Around advcie for `org-list-set-item-visibility'
temporarily modifying `org-list-get-item-end-before-blank'
with `my-org-list-get-item-end-before-blank' which see."
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'org-list-get-item-end-before-blank)
             #'my-org-list-get-item-end-before-blank))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(advice-add 'org-cycle-internal-local :around #'ad-org-list-set-item-visibility)
(advice-add 'org-list-set-item-visibility :around #'ad-org-list-set-item-visibility)
```